# How to use multiple namespaces in DoctrineCacheBundle cacheDriver?

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I know I can setup multiple namespaces for DoctrineCacheBundle in config.yml file. But Can I use one driver but with multiple namespaces?

The case is that in my app I want to cache all queries for all of my entities. The problem is with flushing cache while making create/update actions. I want to flush only part of my cached queries. My app is used by multiple clients. So when a client updates sth in his data for instance in Article entity, I want to clear cache only for this client only for Article. I could add proper IDs for each query and remove them manually but the queries are dynamically used. In my API mobile app send version number for which DB should return data so I don't know what kind of IDs will be used in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think what you want to do can be solved with some configuration magic. What you want it some sort of indexed cache, and for that you have to find a more powerful tool.

You can take a look at [doctrines second level cache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html). Don't know how good it is now (tried it once when it was in beta and did not make the cut for me).

Or you can build your own cache manager. If you do i recommend using redis. The data structures will help you keep you indexes (Can be simulated with memcached, but it requires more work). What I meen by indexes.

You will have a key like client_1_articles where 1 is the client id. In that key you will store all the ids of the articles of client 1. For every article id you will have a key like article_x where x is the id the of article. In this example client_1_articles is a rudimentary index that will help you, if you want at some point, to invalidated all the caches of articles coming from client 1.

The abstract implementation for the above example will end up being a graph like structure over your cache, with possibly

-composed indexes 'client_1:category_1' => {article_1, article_2}

-multiple indexes for one item eg: 'category_1'=>{article_1, article_2, article_3}, 'client_1' => {article_1, article_3}

-etc.

Hope this help you in some way. At least that was my solution for a similar problem.

Good luck with your project,

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: So you mean to use for instance SncRedisBundle, configure it to be used by DoctrineCacheBundle for metadata_cache, result_cache, query_cache and then in Controller while making a query, cache it with $cache = $this->container->get('redis_cache');  $cache->save('article_1', $article); and then save this keys to KEY to Redis? Like $redis->append('client_1', 'article_1');
And then when making an update just remove proper keys with $redis->delete(array('key3', 'key4')); ?

Comment: Something like that, yes. I don't know if you want result cache. I had some problems with it. I only use meta cache, query cache, and i take care of the result cache by myself.